# Join MAX id between two dates

Tags: mysql, join, select, left-join

I'm having a trouble with this join. Basically I just need to know if "warehouse" exists on both tables, but just take the last entry of the desired 'warehouse' between 2 dates.

```
Select c.warehouse, p.id, p.status FROM control c LEFT JOIN payment p ON c.warehouse = p.warehouse WHERE p.date BETWEEN '2018-06-26' AND '2018-06-27'
```

I also tried (It says: Invalid use of group function):

```
Select c.warehouse, p.id, p.status FROM control c LEFT JOIN payment p ON c.warehouse = p.warehouse WHERE p.date BETWEEN '2018-06-26' AND '2018-06-27' && p.id = MAX(p.id)
```

Those are my tables:

```
                              payments                       control
             +---------------------------------------+    +-----------+
             | id  |  warehouse  | status |   date   |    | warehouse |
             +---------------------------------------+    +-----------+
             |19006|    226975   |   DUE  |2018-06-26|    |   226975  |
    MAX ID-> |19066|    226975   |   PAID |2018-06-27|    |   226976  |
             +---------------------------------------+    +-----------+
```

Result Obtained:

```
+--------------------------------------+
| warehouse |  id  | status |   date   |
+--------------------------------------+
|  226975   |19006 |  DUE   |2018-06-26|
+--------------------------------------+
```

In this case I'm obtaining the "first entry", the lower one (id: 19006) and I want "the last" (id: 19066) the max.

Result expected:

```
+--------------------------------------+
| warehouse |  id  | status |   date   |
+--------------------------------------+
|  226975   |19066 |  PAID  |2018-06-27|
+--------------------------------------+
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two requirements.

1. rows where the `warehouse` column is in both tables. Exclude others. That's done with an inner JOIN.
2. the latest entry from the `payments` table. The `id` of that latest entry for each `warehouse` can be retrieved with this subquery.

   ```
     SELECT MAX(id) id, warehouse 
       FROM payments
      GROUP BY warehouse
   ```

Putting it all together:

```
  SELECT p.warehouse, p.id, p.status, p.date
    FROM payments p
    JOIN ( SELECT MAX(id) id, warehouse 
             FROM payments
            GROUP BY warehouse
         ) mm ON p.id = mm.id AND p.warehouse = mm.warehouse
    JOIN control c ON p.warehouse = c.warehouse
```

Answer (score 0):

My version with slight differences from O. Jones.

```
SELECT *
FROM control c
LEFT JOIN payments p ON p.warehouse=c.warehouse AND
                        p.date = (SELECT MAX(p1.date) 
                                  FROM payments p1 
                                  WHERE p1.warehouse=c.warehouse)
WHERE p.date IS NOT NULL;
```